# Object not being converted into string?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to get the onlinestatus of the visitor of my website, but it seems like my php script cant get info? What i want my script to do is return 0 or false if it says so in db, or if it cant find anything, and to return 1 if it says 1 in db.

Here is my code:

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$useronline = $data->query("SELECT online FROM users WHERE id = '".$id."'") or die($data->error);
```

I can't seem to be able to fix it. It might seem like a small problem, but to me it is really annoying. Thank you in advance.

Just FYI; $data is my connection. 
ID is an integer in my database.

The connection is working, and session was started in the top of the file.

Comment: Is the "id" in your database a string or integer? Generally id's should be numbers not strings. Your passing in a string as the id, try taking off the double quotes from $id so its the integer being passed through

Comment: Are you starting your session with session_start(); before you call $_SESSION['id'] right?

Comment: Have you also checked your mysql connection is working properly? If you hardcode a mysql query does it work?

Comment: Why don't you save the online status in the session as well?

Comment: Connection is working, session is started. I dont know what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `$data` is pdo connection try using

`$data->query("SELECT online FROM users WHERE id = '".(int)$id."'")->fetchColumn()`